# show custom image if image not found

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i want to show a custom image if image not found using htacess my images are saved in an folder named "file-logo" and i am trying to use the code below but it is not working i want that all my images should be shown and in case image not found it should send an custom image "unknown.png"

```css
    <filesMatch "\.(jpg|png|gif)$">
    ErrorDocument 404  file-logo/unknown.png
    </filesMatch>0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `ErrorDocument` you can use `mod_rewrite` like this from site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ file-logo/unknown.png [L,NC]
```

This is assuming `http://example.com/file-logo/unknown.png` is a valid URL.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of **ErrorDocument**  use **mod_rewrite** like this from site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ file-logo/unknown.png [L,NC]
```